# Deactivate Geotools INFO logs in JAR

Tags: java, logging, configuration, geotools

I am using Geotools (version 19.2) to fetch some features. To deactivate the Geotools logging (< SEVERE) I tried 2 things:

1. As I understood the logging documentation ([documentation page](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/conventions/code/log.html)):

`Logging.getLogger("org.geotools").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);`

2. Loading a custom logging.properties configuration

The configuration (*logging.properties*) looks like this:

```
# standard log level
.level = WARNING

handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

## limit the messages that are printed on the console to >= WARNING!
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = WARNING
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.encoding = Cp850

# do not use logging files!
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = OFF

## just output geotools logs with level SEVERE!
org.geotools.level = SEVERE
```

Then I am loading the configuration using this code:

```
LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(MyMainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("logging.properties"));
```

Using both approaches I get **NO logging output if I run my program in Eclipse**. If I run my program as a **JAR**-file I get the following **unwanted logging output**:

> Nov. 08, 2018 9:48:13 VORM. org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore
>   getAggregateExpression INFO: Visitor class
>   org.geotools.feature.visitor.CountVisitor has no aggregate attribute.

The INFO log resides from `private Expression getAggregateExpression(FeatureVisitor visitor)` in `JDBCDataStore` (see [GitHub](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/d2a5c6f5475a254b81428005b2094c5e88b20702/modules/library/jdbc/src/main/java/org/geotools/jdbc/JDBCDataStore.java))

Any ideas why the logging configuration does not work for the generated JAR?

Comment: can you check which jvm is used when running in eclipse vs the command line - it is possible that the cli has a properties file in the jre/lib that over rides yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the JConsole (following [answer on Suppress java util logging from 3rd party jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26492711/2284160)) I figured out that my logging configuration was overwritten by my Java installation's *logging.properties* file.

I tried to change the logging configuration in my main method which was wrong.

Initializing my custom logging.properties in a separate class and specifying the needed system property solves the problem!

1. Custom initialization class

   `public class CustomLoggingPropertiesLoader {`

   ```
   // Initialize the global LogManager
   public CustomLoggingPropertiesLoader() {
       try {
           LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(CustomLoggingPropertiesLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("logging.properties"));
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```

   `}`
2. Use system property ("java.util.logging.config.class")

> java
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.class=de.example.logging.CustomLoggingPropertiesLoader
>   -classpath [myclasspath]